# How to read data from serial port of system using c#

Tags: c#, .net, serial-port

I am try to create software for weighing bridge, while try read data using c# code, its showing some other data something like below mentioned

```
)0 12589 00
)0 12589 00
)0 12589 00
)0 12589 00
)0 12589 00
)0 12589 00
```

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string Port = GenDbUtility.GetElixirConfigValue("SERIAL_PORT", Globals.CompCode);

    //<-- This block ensures that no exceptions happen
    if (serialPort1 != null && serialPort1.IsOpen)
        serialPort1.Close();
    if (serialPort1 != null)
        serialPort1.Dispose();
    //<-- End of Block


    serialPort1 = new SerialPort("COM1");       //<-- Creates new SerialPort using the name selected in the combobox
    serialPort1.Encoding = Encoding.ASCII;
    serialPort1.BaudRate = 9660;
    serialPort1.Parity = Parity.None;
    serialPort1.StopBits = StopBits.One;
    serialPort1.DataBits = 50;
    serialPort1.Handshake = Handshake.None;
    serialPort1.RtsEnable = true;
    serialPort1.ReadBufferSize = 4096;
    serialPort1.ReceivedBytesThreshold = 100000;
    serialPort1.NewLine = "\r\n";
    serialPort1.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(serialPort1_DataReceived);
    serialPort1.Open();     //<-- make the comport listen
}

void serialPort1_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    if (serialPort1.IsOpen)
    {
        SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;

        string newVal = sp.ReadExisting().ToString();
        ///string[] qty = newVal.Split(' ');
        //txtQuantity.Invoke(this.myDelegate, new Object[] { qty[3].ToString() });   
        //string[] qty = newVal.Split(' ');
        //decimal Quantity1 = Convert.ToDecimal(qty[0]);
        //decimal Quantity2 = Convert.ToDecimal(qty[1]);
        //decimal Quantity3 = Convert.ToDecimal(qty[2]);
        //decimal Quantity4 = Convert.ToDecimal(qty[3]);
        //txtQuantity.Text = Quantity3.ToString();

        //if (String.Compare(txtQuantity.Text, qty[3]) != 0)
        //{
        //    txtQuantity.Text = Convert.ToString(qty[3]);
        //    //lblweight.Text = Convert.ToString(qty[2]);
        //        //qty[2].ToString();
        //}
    }
}
```

Comment: Each of the bytes in the packet you are reading should mean something. Read the documentation for what they mean. Not all are data.

Comment: Try implementing the SerialPort Reader like in the examples from MSDN (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport(v=vs.110).aspx) There's a whole example class which you can use.

Comment: May try to use a tool to readout the COM-Port to compare the result with them you received. May the item adapted to the COM-Port gives back wrong data.

Answer (score 1):

The serial port does not know how long a "message" is. The device you are reading from will have published some form of protocol you will need to follow for reading in the correct data.

You can not assume `sp.ReadExisting()` will have exactly one message worth's of data, it may have less than a full message and it could combine parts of two messages together and return it as one result (this is the problem you are having). Go read the documentation for the weighing bridge and read only the parts out that you should be reading out.

Answer (score -1):

com ports can be opened like a drive, i.e. COM1:  instead of e.g. C:
I don't use C# enough to know the filesystem functions, but in C/C++ its fopen() et al

Comment: That has nothing to do with the OP's problem. He can open the com port fine, and he gets data from it. He just does not understand why the data he is getting back is not what he expected.